# In Eclipse with m2e, how to get "Quick Javadoc" (F2) to display for Maven dependencies?

Tags: eclipse, javadoc, m2e

In Eclipse (Indigo), with the m2e plugin, I would like to be able to <kbd>F2</kbd> on a method name from a 3rd party dependency (i.e. one that I do not have the source for), and view the Javadoc.

For example, let's say I'm working with the Spring Framework JARs (something that I don't have the source for locally, but it's available in Maven central).

I've found that <kbd>F2</kbd> will work just fine if I have downloaded the sources locally already (i.e. by Ctrl-Clicking into the method); however, <kbd>F2</kbd> does *not* work otherwise, that is, it doesn't display Javadoc.

Any suggestions? I'm even fine if there's a configuration setting making m2e auto-download sources when I hit <kbd>F2</kbd>, it's just really annoying to lose context in order to view documentation!

Thanks in advance. (I believe I have already reviewed similar questions on SO, but none seemed to match my situation exactly.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Right-click` on your Maven project, `Maven` `Download JavaDoc` will download JavaDoc for all your project code to your local Maven repository. Thus you will be able to view the JavaDoc when pressing F2.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I think one of the other issues that I encountered was that one of the dependencies I was trying this with (Spring) doesn't seem to have Javadoc distributed to Maven Central :(

Comment: @PeterMularien Just tried it for a Spring project, and it works for me.

Comment: @RobinGreen, my experience has been that it depends on your Maven settings and what you have in your local .m2 repository. It's also possible this has been fixed in recent versions of m2e.

Comment: After you downloaded the sources & doc, you may need to restart eclipse in order for M2E to link the sources correctly with your project.

Comment: Restarting was absolutely necessary for me. Bugged me for a few minutes. :(

Answer (score 0):

Check out both the 'download artifact Sources' and 'download artifact JavaDoc' in perferences-> maven.
Then restart the eclipse.